# cannot ever figure out how to do texture jobs in twgl

Tags: javascript, glsl, textures, webgl, twgl.js

This is the code I have for vs/fs and a simple cube that I want to put on to my canvas. some of the part is omitted for the sake of lengthiness.

```
<script id="cube-vs" type="notjs">
    precision highhp float;
    attribute vec3 vpos;
    attribute vec3 vnormal;
    attribute vec2 vtex;
    varying vec3 fColor;
    varying vec3 fNormal;
    varying vec2 fTexCoord;

    uniform mat4 view;
    uniform mat4 proj;
    uniform mat4 model;
    uniform vec3 lightdir;
    uniform vec3 cubecolor;

    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(vpos, 1.0);
        vec4 normal = normalize(model * vec4(vnormal,0.0));
        float diffuse = .2 + abs(dot(normal, vec4(lightdir,0.0)));
        fColor = (cubecolor * diffuse);
        fTexCoord = vtex;
    }
</script>
<script id="cube-fs" type="notjs">

    precision highhp float;

    varying vec3 fColor;
    varying vec3 fNormal;
    varying vec2 fTexCoord;

    uniform sampler2D texSampler;

    void main(void) {
        vec4 texColor = texture2d(texSampler, fTexCoord);
        gl_FragColor = vec4(fColor*texColor.xyz,1.0);
    }
</script>
```

the cube

```
...

    Cube.prototype.init = function(drawingState) {
        var gl=drawingState.gl;
        // create the shaders once - for all cubes
        if (!shaderProgram) {
            shaderProgram = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["tree-vs", "tree-fs"]);
        }
        if (!buffers) {
            var arrays = {
                vpos : { numComponents: 3, data: [...] },
                vnormal : {numComponents:3, data: [...]},
                vtex : {numComponents:2, data: [
                    1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,
                    1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,
                    1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,
                    1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,
                    1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,
                    1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,
                ]},
                indices : {[...]}
                };
            buffers = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl,arrays);
        }
        if (!texture) {
            texture = twgl.createTexture(gl, {src:textures/tree.jpg});
        }    
    };
    Cube.prototype.draw = function(drawingState) {
        var modelM = twgl.m4.scaling([this.size*1.4,this.size*1.4,this.size*1.4]);
        twgl.m4.setTranslation(modelM,this.position,modelM);
        var gl = drawingState.gl;
        gl.useProgram(shaderProgram.program);
        twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl,shaderProgram,buffers);
        twgl.setUniforms(shaderProgram,{
            view:drawingState.view, proj:drawingState.proj, lightdir:drawingState.sunDirection,
            cubecolor:this.color, model: modelM, texSampler: texture);
        twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.TRIANGLES, buffers);
    };
```

the cube worked fine without texture
but when I tried to put texture on, it never works
I tried almost everything and I still can't figure out how to put texture on.
so, how can i put texture on?

any hints would be very much appreciated.

*********edit
I have managed to successfully upload the texture coordinates and uniforms
but the image does not show up and the cube is colored light blue.
any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: what does *"it never works"* mean?

Comment: it meant i cannot figure out how to make it work

Comment: What isn't working about it? What do you expect to see and what is it that you're actually seeing?

Comment: I am trying to put on a texture on a cube, but it seems to not work and I am having hard time debugging it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be nice if you could provide a working example instead of just parts of the code. There's several typos in the code above. For example in the `setUniforms` part there's no closing `}`. In the `createTexture` part there's no quotes on the url. You spelled `highp` as `highhp` and `texture2D` as `texture2d`. I assume if you say it's running though without textures those are just transcription errors because if not you should see very clear errors in the JavaScript console.

It's not clear what's wrong but when debugging WebGL the first I'd do is check the JavaScript console. Are there any messages about un-renderable textures?

No? Then the next thing i'd do is change the fragment shader to a solid color

```
<script id="cube-fs" type="notjs">

    precision highhp float;

    varying vec3 fColor;
    varying vec3 fNormal;
    varying vec2 fTexCoord;

    uniform sampler2D texSampler;

    void main(void) {
        vec4 texColor = texture2d(texSampler, fTexCoord);
        gl_FragColor = vec4(fColor*texColor.xyz,1.0);
gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);  // -------ADDED-------------------------
    }
</script>
```

If you see your cube then yes, the issue is related to the texture. If not the issue is somewhere else.

Let's assume you see a red cube. Ok, next thing is to check the texture coordinates. I'd change the fragment shader to this

```
<script id="cube-fs" type="notjs">

    precision highhp float;

    varying vec3 fColor;
    varying vec3 fNormal;
    varying vec2 fTexCoord;

    uniform sampler2D texSampler;

    void main(void) {
        vec4 texColor = texture2d(texSampler, fTexCoord);
        gl_FragColor = vec4(fColor*texColor.xyz,1.0);
gl_FragColor = vec4(fTexCoord,0,1);  // -------CHANGED-------------------------
    }
</script>
```

You should see the cube now with red->green shading. If not you've got bad texture coordinates.

If that looks correct the next thing I might try is put the shader back the way it was originally then check if the variable `texture` is actually set.

There's a bunch of ways I could check this.

1. Use the [WebGL Inspector](https://benvanik.github.io/WebGL-Inspector/)
2. Use the standard JavaScript debugger. Put a breakpoint on the `setUniforms` part. Inspect the variables
3. Do something like this

   ```
   var uniforms = {
       view:drawingState.view, 
       proj:drawingState.proj, 
       lightdir:drawingState.sunDirection,
       cubecolor:this.color, 
       model: modelM, 
       texSampler: texture,
   };
   window.u = uniforms;
   twgl.setUniforms(shaderProgram, uniforms);
   ```

   Now open the JavaScript console and type `u.texSampler`. It should print something like

   ```
   WebGLTexture {}
   ```

   If it doesn't then probably `texture` is not the variable you think it is

One other question is are you rendering constantly using requestAnimationFrame as in

```
function render() {
  // draw stuff like maybe call someCube.draw(drawingState)
  ...
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

I ask because textures are loaded asynchronously so if you are only rendering once then you won't see any textures because they have not yet been loaded.

You have a few options.

1. Render constantly (like the example above)

   twgl will default to a 1x1 pixel texture so rendering should work. Then the image is finally loaded it will update the texture
2. Wait for the texture to load.

   If you don't want to render until the texture is ready then you can add a callback to `twgl.createTexture` and it will call you back when the texture is ready.

The other thing to do is to start with a working sample

```js
var m4 = twgl.m4;                                              // <!------------ ADDED
var v3 = twgl.v3;                                              // <!------------ ADDED

// not sure why these are globals?!???!
var shaderProgram;                                             // <!------------ ADDED
var texture;                                                   // <!------------ ADDED
var buffers;                                                   // <!------------ ADDED
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");                 // <!------------ ADDED
var drawingState = {                                           // <!------------ ADDED
  gl: canvas.getContext("webgl"),                              // <!------------ ADDED
  view: m4.inverse(m4.lookAt([3,3,6], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0])),  // <!------------ ADDED
  proj: m4.perspective(                                        // <!------------ ADDED
    Math.PI * 0.3,                                             // <!------------ ADDED
    canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight,                  // <!------------ ADDED
    0.1, 10),                                                  // <!------------ ADDED
  sunDirection: v3.normalize([2,3,-2]),                        // <!------------ ADDED
};                                                             // <!------------ ADDED


function Cube() {            // <!-------------------------------------- ADDED
  this.size = 1;             // <!-------------------------------------- ADDED
  this.position = [0, 0, 0]; // <!-------------------------------------- ADDED 
  this.color = [1, 1, 1];    // <!-------------------------------------- ADDED
}                            // <!-------------------------------------- ADDED

Cube.prototype.init = function(drawingState) {
  var gl=drawingState.gl;
  // create the shaders once - for all cubes
  if (!shaderProgram) {
    shaderProgram = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["cube-vs", "cube-fs"]);  // <!---- CHANGED
  }
  if (!buffers) {
    var arrays = {
      vpos: { numComponents: 3, data: [1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1], },
      vnormal:  { numComponents: 3, data:  [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1], },
      vtex: { numComponents: 2, data: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], },
      indices:  [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 20, 22, 23],
    };
    buffers = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl,arrays);
  }
  if (!texture) {
    texture = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
      src: "https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5795/21506301808_efb27ed699_q_d.jpg",
      crossOrigin: "", // <!--------- not needed if on same server which "texture/tree.jpg" is
    });
  }    
};

Cube.prototype.draw = function(drawingState) {
  var modelM = twgl.m4.scaling([this.size*1.4,this.size*1.4,this.size*1.4]);
  twgl.m4.setTranslation(modelM,this.position,modelM);
  var gl = drawingState.gl;
  gl.useProgram(shaderProgram.program);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl,shaderProgram,buffers);
  twgl.setUniforms(shaderProgram,{
    view:drawingState.view, proj:drawingState.proj, lightdir:drawingState.sunDirection,
    cubecolor:this.color, model: modelM, texSampler: texture});
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.TRIANGLES, buffers);
};

var cube = new Cube();               // <!------------ ADDED
cube.init(drawingState);             // <!------------ ADDED

function render() {                  // <!------------ ADDED
  var gl = drawingState.gl           // <!------------ ADDED
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);          // <!------------ ADDED
  cube.draw(drawingState);           // <!------------ ADDED
  requestAnimationFrame(render);     // <!------------ ADDED
}                                    // <!------------ ADDED
requestAnimationFrame(render);       // <!------------ ADDED
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script id="cube-vs" type="notjs">
    //precision highp float;    <!---------------- CHANGED
    attribute vec3 vpos;
    attribute vec3 vnormal;
    attribute vec2 vtex;
    varying vec3 fColor;
    varying vec3 fNormal;
    varying vec2 fTexCoord;

    uniform mat4 view;
    uniform mat4 proj;
    uniform mat4 model;
    uniform vec3 lightdir;
    uniform vec3 cubecolor;

    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(vpos, 1.0);
        vec4 normal = normalize(model * vec4(vnormal,0.0));
        float diffuse = .2 + abs(dot(normal, vec4(lightdir,0.0)));
        fColor = (cubecolor * diffuse);
        fTexCoord = vtex;
    }
</script>
<script id="cube-fs" type="notjs">

    precision highp float;  // <!--------- CHANGED (should probably use mediump though)

    varying vec3 fColor;
    varying vec3 fNormal;
    varying vec2 fTexCoord;

    uniform sampler2D texSampler;

    void main(void) {
        vec4 texColor = texture2D(texSampler, fTexCoord);  // < !-------- CHANGED
        gl_FragColor = vec4(fColor*texColor.xyz,1.0);
    }
</script>
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```

One more question, are you running a webserver? WebGL requires a web server to read textures. Note, running a web server is trival. [A really good one is here](https://github.com/cortesi/devd/). Just [download the version for your OS](https://github.com/cortesi/devd/releases) then

```
path/to/devd-download/devd path/to/project
```

Then go to `http://localhost:8000/nameOfYourHtmlFile.html`

I'm assuming this was not the issue because if it was you'd have seen a clear error in the JavaScript console about not being able to load the texture but you haven't mentioned errors in the JavaScript console

Comment: thank you so much. I will try this and see what happens!

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the createTexture part.

Comment: Why do think that? I see nothing wrong with it. Did you try each step. Especially step #1, checking the JavaScript console? Added a working example

Comment: nvm i tried rewriting the whole code and figured out that the texture coordinate is not working.
i have updated the code in the post can you tell me whats wrong with it?

Comment: I managed to implement the texture coordinates and uniforms but the cubes are colored light blue instead of showing the texutre. is there solution for that? and thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Did you [check the JavaScript console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)? What does it show?